# Angular2 [innerHTML] if else validation

Tags: javascript, angular, tags

I want to display different text in a button, depending on some JSON data.

Example (of course not working):

```
<button [innerHTML]='"Male" if user.gender==1 else "Female"'></button>
```

I know this functionality already exisits in e.g [ngClass]:

```
<button [ngClass]='{"btn-success": data.complete, "btn-primary": !data.complete}'>Some text</button>
```

Using the [ngClass] approach is displayed as [object:Object] and therefore not working.

Any solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use ternary expression

```
<button [innerHTML]='user.gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female"'></button>
```

anyway you don't need `innerHtml` for this. I'd do it like:

```
<button>{{ user.gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female" }}</button>
```

Comment: It is the `single quotes` and `double quotes` that got me.

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible way is just bind to a variable as the button text.

Like this

`<button>{{buttonText}}</button>`

and in your `.ts` file, just setting the value of `buttonText` based on your json value.